# my echo command is wrong understood by cmd

Tags: batch-file, echo

I am trying to get this string:

```
echo for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (killinput.txt) do if "%%a"=="stop" exit>> input.bat`
```

in the file input.bat but my batch file prints this string on the screen instead of getting it in the file input.bat

This is my script -->

```
echo for /f "tokens^=1 delims^=" %%%a in ^(killinput.txt^) do if "%%%a"^=^="stop" exit>> input.bat
```

This is my output -->

```
for /f "tokens^=1 delims^=" %%a"^=^="stop" exit>> input.bat
```

I hope you can help me! THNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing. I'm assuming you want the following line in your output file:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (killinput.txt) do if "%%a"=="stop" exit
```

You properly preceded the above with `ECHO`, and added `>>input.bat` to the end. But then you ran into trouble.

The critical thing that needs to happen is each `%` must be escaped as `%%`. So `%%a` needs to become `%%%%a`. But you used `%%%a`. As MC ND has indicated, that mistake fully explains your output. It explains why the IN() clause dissapeared, and also explains why the output is appearing on the screen instead of the output file. The IN() clause and beginning of the DO IF is treated as a non-existent variable name that gets removed. This leads to unbalanced quotes, which means the redirection is now quoted so it is taken as a string literal instead of as redirection.

The other mistake is you escaped a number of quoted characters that should not be escaped. Generally, you either escape special characters, or quote them, but not both. (Of course there are exceptions to every rule).

Also, the `(` never needs to be escaped after ECHO, and the `)` only needs to be escaped if the ECHO is within a parenthesized block.

So, if the line stands on its own, then it can be as simple as:

```
echo for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%%%a in (killinput.txt) do if "%%%%a"=="stop" exit>>input.bat
```

If the line is within a parenthesized block, then it should be:

```
(
  echo for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%%%a in (killinput.txt^) do if "%%%%a"=="stop" exit>>input.bat
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%%%a in (killinput.txt) do if "%%%%a"=="stop" exit >> input.bat
```

The main problem in your sample is the `%%%a` . The first two percent signs output a single percent sign, and the third starts the name of a variable

```
echo for /f "tokens^=1 delims^=" %%%a in ^(killinput.txt^) do if "%%%a"^=^="stop" exit>> input.bat
                                   ^                              ^
      The variable is              %a in ^(killinput.txt^) do if "%
```

As this variable does not contain anything, nothing is echoed for it, and the result is what you got.